# Cron (liebig/cron) breaks Artisan on a fresh Laravel 5 install

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cron, laravel-artisan

In step 4 of the [installation process](https://github.com/liebig/cron#installation), I get an error (below) when trying to run the Artisan migration:

Digging around, I've found a [discussion on the Laracasts forums](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-latest-commit-breaks-if-using-waygenerators-or-image-internvention/) where it's pointed out this could be related to the new structure of Laravel 5.

Anybody has any idea about this?

```
exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'Call to undefined method [package]' in /home/vagrant/myApplication/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/ServiceProvider.php:226
Stack trace:
#0 /home/vagrant/myApplication/vendor/liebig/cron/src/Liebig/Cron/CronServiceProvider.php(22): Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider->__call('package', Array)
#1 /home/vagrant/myApplication/vendor/liebig/cron/src/Liebig/Cron/CronServiceProvider.php(22): Liebig\Cron\CronServiceProvider->package('liebig/cron')
#2 [internal function]: Liebig\Cron\CronServiceProvider->boot()
#3 /home/vagrant/myApplication/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(523): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#4 /home/vagrant/myApplication/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(631): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#5 /home/vagrant/myApplication/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(613): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootProvider(Object(Liebig\Cron\CronServiceProvider))
#6 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Application->Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}(Object(Liebig\Cron\CronServiceProvider), 19)
#7 /home/vagrant/myApplication/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(614): array_walk(Array, Object(Closure))
#8 /home/vagrant/myApplication/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/BootProviders.php(15): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->boot()
#9 /home/vagrant/myApplication/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(165): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders->bootstrap(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application))
#10 /home/vagrant/myApplication/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(192): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
#11 /home/vagrant/myApplication/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(89): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->bootstrap()
#12 /home/vagrant/myApplication/artisan(36): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#13 {main}
```

> [Issue posted in Cron's GitHub.](https://github.com/liebig/cron/issues/55)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for this package with Laravel 5.

The ability to schedule crons is built in from the beginning now.

```
$schedule->command('foo')->daily();
```

[You can read about scheduling artisan commands in the Laravel 5 Docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/artisan#scheduling-artisan-commands)

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out :). However, the package I'm referencing also provides a webhook for online cron services - I could implement that myself, but I'd rather not reinvent the wheel ;).

Comment: Is the webhook to allow an online service to run your cron? Or for your cron to send a command back to an online service that is has successfully run?